# If the field is checked send an email notification

Tags: workflow, formula-field, contracts

I had a requirement where i need to send an email notification 100 days before the contract end date based on the condition.So i have created the workflow rule with the condition and time based workflow ,email alert.Which worked fine.

Now once the 100 days email is sent to the opportunity owner,then their are two fields on contract object "SRR" (picklist field - as yes/no) and "renewed" as a formula field.Now the opportunity owner will update the field "SRR" value and "renewed" .

1)If the owners updates the field "SRR" value as "Yes" then an email needs to send to the customer (customer email is from contact email .how can i get that to send an email )for 45 /30 /15 days before the contract end date.

2)If the owners updates the field "SRR" value as "No" then stop sending  email needs to  the customer .

3)If the owners does not updates the field "SRR" value  within 90 days before the contract end date,then an email needs to be sent to the owner  and superior.

I have created a WFR for 90 days notification with conditions as .

```
(Contract: Contract End DateNOT EQUAL TOnull) AND (Contract: Renewed EQUALSTrue) AND (Contract: SRR EQUALSYes)
```

Now how can i update the formula field as "checked ".

While sending an email alert ,im not getting the contact email(formula field on contract object) to select .

How can i get this filter in WFR .Any help or example very much appreciated.

Comment: After u complete the workflow condition there is an option called "Add workflow option". Upon selecting this option you can choose to update your field to "checked"

Comment: @Marc Zaharescu:Thanks for the response.But before sending the 90 days notification the field should get updated and den only the email will be sent.Prior to that we have a email already going for 100 days and their need to updated .Based on the updation the 90 days WFR should get triggered.Any suggestion .

Answer (score 0):

1  Create a date field on opportunity 100 days email sent,

2.Add field update to the same workflow which sends out email to update this `date` field to `system.today()`

3.create a after update trigger on opportunity

```
if (opportunity op.trigger.new){
  op.srr__C <> trigger.oldmap.get(op.id).srrc
       if (Today - 100daysemail__C ==60) //similarly for 30/15 days
             myemaillibe.sendemail( op.account__r.Contact.emailid) //this will be a sepereate email class  //
}
```

3 If the owners does not updates the field "SRR" value within 90 days before the contract end date,then an email needs to be sent to the owner and superior.
Need to write schedulable batch class for the same
query for batch class ill be all opps with `today-100days =90`
and SRR value = needs a another value for default condition SRR.cannot simply work with yes and no in this case

Comment: :Thanks for the response.When i do an email update for the date field in the formula editor when i use system.today().the system throws an error.Any suggestion please.

Comment: try `today` instead of `system.today()`;

Answer (score 0):

- It's not possible to use a formula field with email address to send email notifications - you can use a field of email type, or Contact, or User lookup (or select any User/Role from the list)
- Formula value is not get updated by anyone - it's recalculated each time the formula field is retrieved (displayed, queried)

You just have to create another workflow with the criteria when you want to send email notifications for 45 /30 /15. And I'm not sure for 90 days - maybe 100 days's WF has to set a flag, and then this flag has to be erased on SRR update or 90 days workflow will trigger otherwise.